# Updating text not working

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to click the button, and have the text in the span change to the content in the function. Any help would be appreciated!

```
function UpdateText(){
    document.getElementById(bar).innerHTML= "hey";
}
```

```
<span id="bar">sup</span>
<button onClick="UpdateText()">hi</button>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47xbwkwy/)

Comment: When you ask a question, the "Title" section says "What's your programming question?  Be specific".  Your title in no way conveys your question.

Comment: I removed a lot of the fluff from your question. We don't need to know how new you are at programming. Now, what's your actual problem. What is not working there?

Comment: The span isn't changing upon clicking the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `bar` inside quotes.

```
document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML= "hey";
```

In the fiddle, you should set the dropdown at "Frameworks & Extensions" to "No wrap - in `<head>`". This does the same as having the `UpdateText()` function in your `<head>` tag, and then it works.

Comment: Or leave the quotes out and omit `document.getElementBy(` and `)`...

Comment: What iamnotmaynard said: even when adding the quotes, the jsfiddle doesn't work.

Comment: @nfwright The answer is correct. Your fiddle doesn't work because you have it set to run the JS code "onload".  Change it to nowrap head.  This is an issue with the fiddle, not the code.  If the code is wrapped in a window onload event the function is not available when the DOM loads.

Comment: so how do I go about fixing that, should I just use a different program?

Comment: @nfwright I updated my answer, and also explained that. You need to put the `UpdateText` function in your `<head>` tag.

Comment: Yep. Not that the issue with jsFiddle was the actual problem, but now OP can see it works.